# Error when using function import in solidity and vscode

Tags: solidity, contract-development

What am I doing wrong? When I use the ctrl + left mouse key combination, vscode displays the Transfer function in the ERC20.sol file with no errors. But when I call the Transfer function at the file that uses the import file ERC20.sol, I get this error

[image]

The contents of the Transfer function at ERC20.sol are:

```
  event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are following this or an equivalent interface:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


/**
 * @title ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 */
interface IERC20 {
  function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

  function balanceOf(address _who) external view returns (uint256);

  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender)
    external view returns (uint256);

  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external returns (bool);

  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
    external returns (bool);

  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value)
    external returns (bool);

  event Transfer(
    address indexed from,
    address indexed to,
    uint256 value
  );

  event Approval(
    address indexed owner,
    address indexed spender,
    uint256 value
  );
}
```

If so, `Transfer` here is an event, not a function. Thus, if you are intending to emit an event, you should preface the event call with `emit`:

```
emit Tranfer(...);
```

Read more here: [Solidity // Contracts // Events](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#events).

Comment: I'm actually using this interface. So your idea is that I should change the Transfer (msg.sender, _to, _value) to emit Transfer (msg.sender, _to, _value)

Comment: What are you expecting that line of code to do? Take a look at [this](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L67) which looks to be exactly what you are trying to emulate. It looks to me like you want to emit an event, thus yes you should simply add `emit` to the beginning of the line.

Comment: I did not use `is TokenInterface` after `import "./TokenInterface .sol"`. This causes Vscode to not determine the Transfer event. Thank you so much.